# Device Manager fails to find Android debug USB connection

Tags: android, debugging, connection, usb, failed-installation

I have tried with zero success to get a USB debug connection from a WinXP dev box to a brand X Android 1.6 tablet. I believe I had everything configured correctly on the Android and installed correctly on the dev box, but when the two are connected with a USB cable NOTHING HAPPENS; i.e. Windows finds no new hardware much less a new USB device; therefore, I cannot then install the Android SDK USB drivers on Windows and do the debug thing with Eclipse.

Either the mfg of the Android tablet device has disabled USB debugging and just didn't remove the UI that appears to enable it -- or I've left out some crucial step(s). (The device manual is 100% Chinese and I'm 0% Chinese, so it's no help. The tablet is very nearly, but not, the model A84 7" touch screen 'laptop' at 'www.lezestar.com' in case this helps.)

On the tablet:

• 'Settings/Application/Development/USB Debugging' is enabled.

• Tried 'Settings/Application/Development/Allow mock locations' enabled and not.

• Has 500MB internal flash 'hard disk'

• Has installed 2G SD card

• Firmware: 1.6

• Kernel:   2.6.29-002360g4f8dbbb-dirty

• Build No: 1.7.3

On Dev box:

• Windows XP SP3

• Device Manager finds no 'new hardware' when XP<-->Android USB cable is connected.

• Neither USBDeview.exe (Nirsoft) nor USBView.exe (Microsoft) find any evidence of connection with the Android

• Eclipse Galileo (3.5.2) with Android SDK (for 1.6) and ADV Manager.

• USB Driver package, rev 3. downloaded using ADV Manager.

Other:

• USB ports on both Tablet and dev box successfully connect a USB mouse.

• Tablet and Windows XP have been rebooted often.

Is permanently disabling debugging something that Android manufacturors are allowed to do and therefore I'm trying something that can't be done?

If the mfg has 'disabled' debugging, is there a way to work around this; e.g. download a tool that can change Android OS configuration to reenable it?

Thanks in advance for ideas on what I've missed or could try.

Paul S...

Answer (score 1):

> Windows finds no new hardware much
>   less a new USB device

I doubt that is something we're going to be able to help much with. It feels as though there is a general USB setting that may be turned off, as I would expect you to at least have an option for mass storage mode. If their docs are online, is there a way you can run them through Google Translate or something?

> Is permanently disabling debugging
>   something that Android manufacturors
>   are allowed to do

You will notice that your tablet probably does not have the Android Market. If so, the manufacturer worked off the Android open source tree and can do whatever it wants. The Android Market is your "seal of approval" from Google and means, among other things, that `adb` and the other dev tools will work.

Answer (score 0):

CommonsWare, thanks for your reply.

> Google translate

I can't find the device online , much less specs or manual, but after posting my question, I realized that the RAM and flash of the device I received were half the size advertised (i.e. not the model advertised), so I am returning it.

> Android Market

Thanks to you, I will be a more informed buyer this time around and be sure that my next purchase is guaranteed to work as a development device.

Paul S...